# How to print specified array value

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

I am fetch facebook user's working history, and when I `print_r`, I get an array like this:

```
Array (
    [work] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [employer] => Array (
                [id] => 111178415566505 
                [name] => Liputan 6 SCTV
            )
      ) [1] => Array (
            [employer] => Array (
                [id] => 107900732566334
                [name] => SCTV
            )
        )
    ) 
    [id] => 502163984
)
```

How do I display only the value from `name`, so the output will be like this:

```
Liputan 6 SCTV
SCTV
```

I used `foreach`, but always an error always happens.

Comment: Something like `$your_variable['work'][0]['employer']['name']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($array['work'] as $arr) {
    echo $arr['employer']['name']."<br>\n";
}
```

This is assuming your data looks like:

```
$array = array(
    'work' => array(
        array(
            'employer' => array('id' => 111178415566505, 'name' => 'Liputan 6 SCTV'),
        ),
        array(
            'employer' => array('id' => 107900732566334, 'name' => 'SCTV'),
        ),
    ),
    'id' => 502163984,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

for instance your array variable name is $test, then you can get name value by

```
$test['work'][0]['employer']['name']
```

you can check your array structure using pre tag, like

```
 echo '<pre>';print_r($test);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_reduce, implode, and closure (PHP 5.3+) to do this.

```
echo implode("<br/>", array_reduce($array["work"],
    function(&$arr, $v){ 
        $arr[] = $v["employer"]["name"];
    },array()
));
```

Comment: this may very well be the most convoluted way to solve this, but its fun.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$arr` is working history array. You can use `for` Then array look like this :

```
for($i=0, $records = count( $arr['work']); $i < $records; $i++) {
    echo $arr['work'][$i]['employer']['name'] ."<br>";
}
```

Using `foreach`

```
foreach( $arr['work'] as $works) {
    echo $works['employer']['name'] ."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($your_array as $your_array_item)
{
    echo $your_array_item['work'][0]['employer']['name'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$count=count($array);

for($i=0,$i<=$count;$i++){
echo $array['work'][$i]['employer']['name'];
}
```

This will work.. Dynamically..

Comment: Condition should be `$i < $count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array['work'] as $val_arr) {
    echo $val_arr['employer']['name']."<br />";
}
```